# Best Way to Extract Different Types of Data from Text File

Tags: c#

I am working on a problem where I need to extract data from text. I first considered using regular expressions, but some of the data is not in a format I am sure how to handle or even if regex is the best way to handle it.  So, some lines are simple `[fieldname]: value \newline`.  Unfortunately, others have nested data, such as contacts.  Here is an example:

```
Contacts: last update 11/30/2015 10:25 AM (PST)

          Dispatch and Operations: Mike (Dispatcher) (Primary Contact)
          Phone: 111-111-1111          Fax: 111-111-1111
          Email: test@yahoo.com
          Owner or Officer: Jane Doe (President)
          Phone: 222-222-2222          Fax: 111-111-1111
          Email: test@yahoo.com

SERVICES: last update 11/12/2016 03:41 PM (PST)
```

You will see it has a start piece of text I can find, but I only want the two contacts below, excluding the last update time.  Additionally, the first line of the contact is their title, not something I can count on for pattern matching since it is a freeform field.  Now, I could go line by line, but this would mean I need to hard code this knowledge into my code.  I tried Googling it, but I haven't been able to find something that addresses this issue.  So, what I am hoping is that someone can help me with some direction to help me get back on track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing data that's not in a well-defined format is always tricky. You can work with heuristics (for example, field names that are not `Phone` or `Email` denote role or department info) but that only works until it breaks because someone adds data that doesn't conform to your rules.

For this case, it might be easiest to define a number of line types with corresponding regex patterns which are tried in order, and a parser which handles the structure according to some grammar:

```
ContactInfo =
    RoleOrDepartmentLine
    (PhoneLine | EmailLine)+
```

Of course, this quickly gets messy if there are special cases or exceptions.

If this is for a one-time data import, you will probably be able to cope with less than 100% accuracy, fixing the misread data manually. However, if you plan an ongoing data import, you should absolutely insist on a well-defined interchange format (not CSV).

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no control over the sender, so I am stuck with having to work around it.  I was going to say that the real problem here is not having the information sent to me in a format that is easy to parse.  Oh well, I appreciate the help.